# How to create x-axis range groups with Crossfilter and dc.js?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Here is a fiddle to help show what I'd like to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/m4x7o5of/

I have a set of records, each with a float value. For example:

```
var records = [{name: 'record1', value: 1.34563}, ..., {name: 'record5000', value: 0.62974}];
```

I'd like to create a barchart in dc.js that plots the records on the x-axis in range buckets, e.g x-number of records with value between 0 and .5, y-number of records between .5 and 1, z-number of records between 1 and 1.5, and so on.

I'm using an ordinal scale so that I can divide the set of records into 5ths, but I can't figure out how to get the records grouped together in the ranges like I described. In the linked fiddle, only the records with a value that matches the plotted ordinals will get displayed right now.

Is it even possible to group the records like this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dimension.group takes a function that you can use to derive the group key. So `dimension.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d); });` will give you group keys of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 for your data set. You'll just need to construct a function that returns the values you want based on the values in your data set. Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: Cool, so with that grouping function I get something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m4x7o5of/1/. Only issue here is that values above 8 are cut off. This is getting closer to what my end goal is though. Not sure how I'd get a grouping system like this working for values where the the min is 0 and max is 1 as well. So if I divide the x-axis into 5ths or 6ths I get x-ranges of 0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1 and be able to see the number of records whose value is between .4 and .6.

Comment: I was able to build on top of your answer more and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/mkdjy0up/. The first graph groups records from the dimension with valueOne ranging between 0 and 1, and the second groups records with a valueTwo between 0 and 10. The issue I notice now is that clicking on a bar in one graph causes all of the bars in the other graph to disappear.

Comment: I believe it's filtering the dimension based on the new group key, which isn't going to work properly. You'll want to add a filter handler (https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#filterhandlerfunction) and apply a range filter to the dimension after you convert the group key back to the range it originally covered on the data set.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help Ethan. This is the solution I eventually came up with for displaying records that match the ranges I select: http://jsfiddle.net/4t8ovv63/. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by converting the group key, but if the solution in this fiddle isn't awful I'll use this then. The second graph does something weird with the x-axis, though, if the number of records increases to something large like 100k, but I'll mark your answer as the solution and can figure out the other quirks later.

Comment: You've got the right idea. The default filter that dc.js will apply is a single-value filter and you need to convert it to a range. One thing you could change is to iterate through the filters and figure out your ranges outside of the dimension.filter function, then use a simplified data structure inside the function. This function is going to get called for every record in your data set on every filter operation, so you want to make it as efficient as possible.